# How many ways are there to place the ball in N different bags under given condition?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In how many ways we can put $r$ distinct objects into $n$  baskets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205486/in-how-many-ways-we-can-put-r-distinct-objects-into-n-baskets)

I have a doubt in following Combinatorics  question :
There are N bags, and there several balls of 4 colors (R,G,B,Y).Each bag should be filled by exactly one ball with the following  condition -

-The color of ball in the consecutive bags must be different.

-The color of ball in first and last must be distinct too.

How many ways are there?

For N=2:

```
B-1|B-2
R   G
R   B
R   Y
G   R
G   B
G   Y
B   R
B   G
B   Y
Y   R
Y   G
Y   B
```

For N=3

```
B-1 B-2 B-3
R   G   B
R   G   Y
R   B   G
R   B   Y
R   Y   G
R   Y   B
G   R   B
G   R   Y
G   B   R
G   B   Y
G   Y   R
G   Y   B
B   R   G
B   R   Y
B   G   R
B   G   Y
B   Y   R
B   Y   G
Y   R   G
Y   R   B
Y   G   R
Y   G   B
Y   B   R
Y   B   G
```