# How to find the Circular permutation with Repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In how many ways we can put $r$ distinct objects into $n$  baskets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205486/in-how-many-ways-we-can-put-r-distinct-objects-into-n-baskets)

Need some guidance with the following problem :
There are 'n' different types of objects which needs to be placed in a circle of length 'r' , such that no two adjacent items are of the same type. Repetition is allowed.

```
eg. n = 4 {a,b,c,d} and r = 3 , the circular permutations are 
a b c
a b d
a c b
a c d
a d b
a d c
b c d
b d c
```

We do not include a permutation like 'b d a' , since that is the same as 'a b d'. Nor do we include a permutation like 'a a d' or 'a d a' since they do not satisfy the adjacency condition.

Similarly for n = 4 {a,b,c,d} and r = 4, 
'a b a b' is valid, but 'a b b c' is not.

Is there a general solution or method that I can follow to solve this problem?

Comment: Same question [was asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205486/in-how-many-ways-we-can-put-r-distinct-objects-into-n-baskets) recently. It has been asked a few times in the last couple of days, Same problem, same source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

There is a good article about combinations and variations in [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G).
You need for "Combinations (i.e., without Repetition)" there.

Also if you familar with C# you can use simple and short [solution from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1898744/1046374).