# Number of n digits having no same consecutive digits and same first and last digit

Tags: permutations

We have to form a number of n digits having digits from 1 to 9. Constraint is that first and last digit must be same and no two consecutive digits must be same. How many such number of n digits can be there?

Comment: $n$ has to be larger than $2$ then? Try some examples...! Is this homework?

Comment: Not a homework. Came through it while practicing a problem.

Comment: I guess $n=1$ would fit the constraints given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first and last digits have to be the same, this is the same as asking how many ways there are to colour $n-1$ points on a circle with $9$ colours such that any two adjacent points have different colours. The answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205486/in-how-many-ways-we-can-put-r-distinct-objects-into-n-baskets/205501#205501): $(-1)^{n-1}(9-1)+(9-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot8+8^{n-1}$