# How many ways are there of coloring $n$ numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In how many ways can we colour $n$ baskets with $r$ colours?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205486/in-how-many-ways-can-we-colour-n-baskets-with-r-colours)

How many ways are there of coloring $n$ numbers $1, 2, 3, \dots, n$ ($n \ge 2$) in a circle $(C)$ with $p$  colors ($p \ge 2$), such that each number is given one color, and every color isn't used for two adjacent number? Thanks!

Comment: It is going to be something like $p(p-1)^{n-1}(p-2)$, but for example already for $p=2$ it is not that straightforward (depends also on *parity* of $n$).

Comment: This is not a duplicate because baskets are indistinguishable and numbers are not.

Comment: @sperners: I don't think I've ever seen indistinguishable baskets, but it doesn't matter, since my answer to that question treats them as distinguishable.