# Chromatic Polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I am asked the following:

> Let n be a positive integer at least 3.
>
> The wheel W_n is the graph obtained by taking the cycle C_n, placing
>   an additional vertex at the center, and joining it to each of the
>   other n vertices on the rim using n more  edges (spokes).
>
> Find the chromatic polynomial for W_n.

I know that the form of a [chromatic polynomial](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph#section_2) of a wheel graph looks like:
$${P_w}_n(x)= x((x-2)^{n-1} - (-1)^n(x-2))  $$
The equation above doesn't  take into acount the "vertex at the center" as asked in the question. 
I am confused on how to proceeding with this problem in order to find the chromatic polynomial $W_n$ any help or guidance is welcome.

Comment: Note that math formatting works in block quotes just like it works elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a different numbering than Wikipedia; your $W_n$ is Wikipedia's $W_{n+1}$. Thus you need to substitute $n+1$ for $n$, yielding the chromatic polynomial

$$x((x-2)^n-(-1)^{n+1}(x-2))\;.$$

To find this polynomial, note that you need one colour for the centre and the remaining $x-1$ colours for the remaining vertices, which form a cycle $C_n$. The number of colourings of $C_n$ with $r$ colours is calculated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205501), and substituting $x-1$ for $r$ and multiplying by $x$ for the number of choices for the colour of the centre yields the above polynomial.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, Could you expand on your answer. I tried doing the problem out and got stuck with: $$x\{(x-2)^{n-1}[\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} (-1)^{j+1}(x-2)^{-j-1} ](x-1)+ (-1)^h(x-2)(x-1)(x-3)\}$$ not sure where to go from here or if this is even right. (This is using the wikipedia notation not the questions notation)

Comment: @Nick: It's hard to say anything about that without knowing how you derived it. Did you follow the link? There's a complete derivation of the result there.

Comment: I didn't, sorry I over looked the link thanks!

Comment: @Nick: The chromatic polynomial of a cycle graph is also derived in the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052591/prove-chromatic-polynomial-of-n-cycle).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution in [this paper](http://www.cs.elte.hu/blobs/diplomamunkak/mat/2009/hubai_tamas.pdf) on page 10.