# Prove chromatic polynomial of n-cycle

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let graph $C_n$ denote a cycle with $n$ edges and $n$ vertices where $n$ is a nonnegative integer. Let $P(G, x)$ denote the number of proper colorings of some graph $G$ using $x$ colors.

Theorem: $P(C_n,x)=(x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1)$

By graph reduction,

$P(C_n,x)=$ $P(P_{n-1},x)-P(C_{n-1},x)=P(P_{n-1},x)-P(P_{n-2},x)+P(C_{n-2},x)$.

If I continue to expand, I can write the expression using only paths:

$P(C_n,x)=P(P_{n-1},x)-P(P_{n-2},x)+\dots+(-1)^{n+1}P(P_0,x))$

The number of proper colorings of a simple path is $x(x-1)^{n-1}$. So

$P(C_n,x)=x(x-1)^{(n-1)-1}-x(x-1)^{(n-2)-1}+\dots+(-1)^{n+1}x(x-1)^{-1}$.

Have I made any mistakes? Is it possible to prove the theorem using this method or should I be using induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake at the beginning. The reduction should be
$$P(C_n,x)=P(P_n,x)-P(C_{n-1},x)$$
which holds for $n\ge2$. I don't know what $P_0$ means. We have:
$$P(C_1,x)=0$$
$$P(C_2,x)=P(P_2,x)-P(C_1,x)=P(P_2,x)-0=P(P_2,x)$$
$$P(C_3,x)=P(P_3,x)-P(C_2,x)=P(P_3,x)-P(P_2,x)$$
$$P(C_4,x)=P(P_4,x)-P(P_3,x)+P(P_2,x)$$
$$P(C_5,x)=P(P_5,x)-P(P_4,x)+P(P_3,x)-P(P_2,x)$$
and in general (for $n\ge2)$
$$P(C_n,x)=P(P_n,x)-P(P_{n-1},x)+\cdots+(-1)^nP(P_2,x)$$
$$=x(x-1)^{n-1}-x(x-1)^{n-2}+\cdots+(-1)^nx(x-1)$$
$$=\frac{x(x-1)^{n-1}+(-1)^nx}{1+(x-1)^{-1}}$$
$$=(x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1).$$

Comment: What are $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: $C_1$ is a *loop*, consisting of a vertex $v$ and an edge from $v$ to $v$; since the endpoints of an edge must have different colors, $C_1$ has **no** proper coloring. $C_2$ has two vertices joined by two "parallel" edges; in the context of vertex coloring, it's equivalent to $P_2$. If you want to stick to [*simple* graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html), you can start the recursion with $P(C_3,x)=P(P_3,x)-P(P_2,x)$ which you can easily verify, and go on from there.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. What happens on the second to last line of the proof?

Comment: Summing a finite geometric progression:$$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{m-1}=\frac{a-ar^m}{1-r};$$ in this case the first term is $a=x(x-1)^{n-1}$, the ratio is $r=-(x-1)^{-1}$, and the number of terms is $m=n-1$.