# Let $W_n$ be the wheel graph on $n+1$ vertices. Find $χ(W_n;k)$.

Tags: graph-theory

The first thing I did was I drew $W_6$. Now how do I find the chromatic number of that and what is $k$?

Comment: $n+1$ vertices with the vertex in the middle that connects to all the other vertices around it. Yes, it's chi (I didn't know how to format that). Let me look in my book for chromatic polynomial...I believe if I recall is that $k$ is the degree of each vertex...

Comment: $\chi(W_n;k)$ is the number of ways to properly color $W_n$ using at most $k$ colors.

Comment: Well if we're starting with even amount of vertices, there will be $k$ colors on the middle vertex, and then going outwards, there would be $k-1$ colors, and then going to the next outer vertex would be $k-2$ colors, then we could use $k-1$ colors adjacent to the previous....all in all, there would be $k{(k-1)^\frac {n}{2}}{(k-2)^\frac {n}{2}}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Well that's because I didn't continue my argument since if I did...I would've been saying it $\frac {n}{2}$ times for $(k-1)$ and $\frac {n}{2}$ for $(k-2)$.

Comment: @nyorkr23 Sorry, I fixated on the wrong thing. At step three and beyond, there are exactly two colors you need to avoid, so you are not alternating back and forth between $k-1$ and $k-2$.

Comment: So I should be alternating by $k-2$ colors? And in that post that you posted, why are the exponents $n$ and $n+1$ if there are only $n+1$ vertices with one vertex is different from all the rest, and the leftover vertices $n$ should have alternating colors? Shouldn't it be $\frac {n}{2}$?

Comment: @AustinMohr Yes, but for clarity you might add that vertices and colors are labeled.

Comment: What do you mean labeled?

Comment: @bof As I'm reading the duplicate, should the exponents be as I mentioned or should the exponents be $n$ and $n+1$ as it's displayed on there? I don't get why they did $n$ and $n+1$ if there's only $n$ vertices without the center vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Notation varies, but according to your comment $W_n(x)$ is a [wheel graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph) with $n+1$ vertices.

Given a graph $G$ and a natural number $k,$ the [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) $\chi(G;k)$ is the number of ways that $G$ can be properly colored with a given set of $k$ colors, without necessarily using all of them. It is a polynomial function of $k.$

If you already know the chromatic polynomial of the cycle graph, namely
$$\chi(C_n;k)=(k-1)^n+(-1)^n(k-1),$$
(you can find a derivation in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052591/prove-chromatic-polynomial-of-n-cycle)) then finding the chromatic polynomial of the wheel graph is easy:
$$\chi(W_n;k)=k\chi(C_n;k-1)=k[(k-2)^n+(-1)^n(k-2)].$$
I.e., first pick a color for the central vertex, then color the vertices of the cycle with the remaining $k-1$ colors.

**Example:** $W_3=K_4,$ and
$$\chi(W_3;k)=k[(k-2)^3)-(k-2)]$$$$=k(k-2)[(k-2)^2-1]$$$$=k(k-2)(k^2-4k+3)$$$$=k(k-2)(k-1)(k-3)$$$$=k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)$$$$=\chi(K_4;k).$$