# Chromatic polynomial of cycle $C_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How we can proof that chromatic polynomial of cycle $C_n$ is
$$ w(x) =(x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1) $$
I saw [algebraic proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052591/prove-chromatic-polynomial-of-n-cycle?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I am really interested in combinatoric proof of this fact

We choose random element (without lost of generality) and give him one of $x$ colour.
$$ w(x) = x \cdot ... $$
Now we choose color for right neighbour on $(x-1)$ ways. And again for next right neighbour we choose in $(x-1)$ ways next color. We repeat that as long as we don't meet first vertex. So 
$$ w(x) = x(x-1)^n \neq (x-1)^n+(-1)^n(x-1) $$

Comment: So according to you the chromatic polynomial of $C_3$ is $x(x-1)^2$? Are you sure there are $x-1$ ways to color the last vertex?

Comment: @bof 1. fixed 2. unfortunately no... it is $x(x-1)(x-2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us count the number of ways to color $C_n$ using $x$ colors. We let color $x$ be special, and consider all colorings of the cycles using the first $x-1$ colors. We also fix some orientation of the cycle.

Let us suppose first that not all vertices are colored using the same color. In that case, we can partition the colors into *runs*, each consisting of vertices colored using the same color. We switch the color of every second vertex, starting with the second, to color $x$. The resulting coloring is a valid coloring by construction. Also, this mapping is one-to-one, since we can recover the original coloring by replacing the color of each vertex colored $x$ with the color of its preceding neighbor.

If $n$ is odd then we cannot fix in this way a coloring in which all vertices are colored the same, so we get $(x-1)^n-(x-1)$ colorings. If $n$ is even then we can fix this coloring in two ways, so we get $(x-1)^n-(x-1)+2(x-1) = (x-1)^n+(x-1)$ colorings.