# Finding the Chromatic Polynomial for the wheel graph $W_5$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> Let $G$ be a graph and let $k \in N$. The chromatic polynomial $P_G(k)$ is the
>   number of distinct $k$-colourings if the vertices of G.

Standard results for chromatic polynomials:

> 1) $G = N_n$,  $P_G(k) = k^n$ (Null graphs with $n$ vertices)
>
> 2) $G = K_n$,  $P_G(k) = \frac{k!}{(k-n)!}$ (Complete graph with $n$ vertices)
>
> 3) When G is a tree with $n$ vertices, $P_G(k) = k(k-1)^{n-1}$
>
> 4) $G = C_n$ (for $n \geq 3$),   $\quad P_G(k) = (k-1)^n +(-1)^n(k-1)$. (Cycle graph with $n$ vertices)

Given these standard results I could be asked to find the chromatic polynomial of the Wheel graph $W_n$. Where $W_n$ is defined to be the graph formed by joining each vertex of $C_{n-1}$ to one more vertex.

[image]

I have found a proposition:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges.
>
> For each edge $e$ of $G$, $P_G(k) = P_{G-e}(k) - P_{G\backslash e}(k)$

Using this result to decompose $W_5$:

The chromatic polynomial of $W_5$ is equal to the CP of ($W_5$ minus and edge) - the CP of $W_5$ with the middle vertex contracted to one of the vertices of $C_4$. As I believe the chromatic polynomial is not affected by double edges I can remove all the multiple edges from $W_5$ with the middle vertex contracted to one of the vertices of $C_4$ and hence I get $C_4$.

Continuing the same method as above for $W_5$ minus 2 edges...

I iterated this until my calculation reduced to the CP of $C_4 \cup N_1$ - CP of $C_4$.

Adding all the elements together I got the following:

$$C_4 \cup N_1 - 4 C_4$$

Also, if $G$ is disconnected then $P_G(k)$ is the product of the chromatic polynomials of all the components.

Given the standard results and the above statement I thought that

$P_{W_5}(k) = k\times P_{C_4}(k) - 4P_{C_4}(k)$

$P_{W_5}(k) = (k-4)\times P_{C_4}(k)$

$P_{W_5}(k) = (k-4)\times \left[(k-1)^4 +(-1)^4(k-1)\right]$

$P_{W_5}(k) = (k-4)\times \left[(k-1)^4 +(k-1)\right]$

$P_{W_5}(k) = k^5 - 8k^4 +22k^3-27k^2+12k$

Which is not even close to the formula I found here : [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WheelGraph.html)

$$P_{W_n}(k) = k\left[(k-2)^{n-1} - (-1)^n(k-2)\right]$$

$$P_{W_5}(k) = k\left[(k-2)^{4} - (k-2)\right] = k^5 - 8k^4 +24k^3-33k^2+18k$$

Could anyone please point out where I went wrong and give me some intuition how to solve this type of problems in general?
Any resources where I could find worked out examples?

Comment: How to solve this? Each $k$-coloring of $W_n$ corresponds exactly to the choice of a color for the center of $W_n$ plus the choice of a coloring of $C_n$ based on the $k-1$ remaining colors. Thus, indeed, $$P_{W_n}(k)=k\cdot P_{C_{n-1}}(k-1).$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: ?? Please elaborate on what is not already *elaborated* enough to your taste in my first comment.

Comment: I understand your above comment but don't know how I would get to such a result for example if my graph is not just a $W_n$ but an added vertex to the outside.

Comment: Indeed, if the graph is not $W_n$ then my comment does not apply (?!?).  Be aware though that your question in its present form is awfully close to asking for a way to compute the chromatic polynomial of *any* graph--which is definitely too vague to be asked here.

Comment: I agree with you. It is though for a test preparation and I am bit confused about the method we are supposed to use. I got the wrong answer for $W_5$, which is a bit worrying as there are many more complex graphs that we could be asked. I am mainly trying to understand why I went wrong with my calculations and not how I am supposed to solve the chromatic polynomial for all graphs.

Comment: Then, if this is what you are interested in, you should (greatly) expand on the paragraph "I have done 4 iterations of the above result and got the following: $C_4 \cup N_1 - 4 C_4$".

Comment: I have added in the steps I have done. Given these, would you be able to suggest where I went wrong?

Comment: "Remov(ing) all the multiple edges from $W_5$ with the middle vertex contracted to one of the vertices of $C_4$" does not yield $C_4$, but $C_4$ *plus an edge between one pair of opposing vertices of $C_4$*.

Comment: Thank you, now I see how I went wrong with this calculation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chromatic Polynomial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250883/chromatic-polynomial)

Answer (score -3):

The correct answer is 
$k((k-2)^4+(-1)^4 (k-2)) = k^5-8k^4+24k^3-31k+14k = k(k-1)(k-2)(k^2-5k+7)$

Comment: This is not an answer to the question in the OP.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco What else is there to do but to correctly expand the expression for $P_{W_5}$?